# Webscrape a specific part of a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

My webscrape stopped working. The owner changed the html.

I believe it is the `Set allElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("el-col el-col-8")` line that needs changing.

I am trying to grab text from the webpage that includes the "52-week Range (undefined)" section. I managed to grab text from before and after but not the section I need. An example webpage is https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/gliba/summary and my code should fill my cell with "38.72 - 73.63" after I do some trimming.

I need to do it this way so I can get my head round it and change it in the future when necessary so please just focus on correcting my set line of code (assuming that is the problem!) rather than a whole new more sophisticated method as it will be beyond me. (My other set line of code does what I want it to do.)

```vb
Sub get_title_header()
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim incomeStmtURLs As Variant
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim allRowOfData As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim allElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim anElement As IHTMLElement
Dim aCell As HTMLTableCell

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call ToggleEvents(False)

incomeStmtURLs = Range("Sheet1!h1:h2").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(incomeStmtURLs)

    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = incomeStmtURLs(i, 1)

    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = False

    While wb.Busy
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = wb.document

    On Error GoTo err_clear

    Set allElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("el-col el-col-8")
    While allElements.Length = 0
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        DoEvents
    Wend
    x = allElements(0).innerText
    ' Debug.Print x
    Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Trim(Replace(Mid(x, InStr(1, x, "52-Week Range (undefined)") + 25, 25), vbLf, ""))

    Set allElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("fs-x-large fc-primary fw-bolder")

    x = allElements(0).innerText
    Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Trim(Replace(Mid(x, InStr(1, x, "$") + 1, 7), vbLf, ""))

err_clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit

Next i

Call ToggleEvents(True)

End Sub

Sub ToggleEvents(blnState As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = blnState
    Application.EnableEvents = blnState
    If blnState Then Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If blnState Then Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: what are you getting as output from allElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("el-col el-col-8") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page dynamically updates content as you scroll down. You likely need to scroll that part of the page into view then use grab all the elements with classname statictics-item then take the n-2 index e.g. Without the scrolling part:

```
Set elems = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("statictics-item")
If elems.length > 1 Then Debug.print elems(elems.length-2).innerText
```

For future readers (I know OP doesn't want this):

I would avoid the whole scrolling pickle, dynamic html and browser and issue an xmlhttp request and regex out the appropriate values from the javscript objects the web page uses for updating. N.B. I would probably add in validation on regex match positions.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim r As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/gliba/summary", False
        .send
        r = GetMatches(.responseText, "price52wlow:(.*?),|price52whigh:(.*?),")
        If r <> "NA" Then MsgBox r
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetMatches(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As String
    Dim matches As Object

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern

        'If .test(inputString) Then
        Set matches = .Execute(inputString)

        If matches.Count = 2 Then
            GetMatches = matches.Item(0).submatches(0) & "-" & matches.Item(1).submatches(1)
        Else
            GetMatches = "NA"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Regex:

[image]

Comment: thank you QHarr, not the first time you have helped me. The second solution is of course beyond me, in fact I am struggling to workout how to scroll down the window (spent about 45 mins trying to find a solution so far!). Really helpful though, I didn't know it was because it was a dynamic webpage

Comment: If you interested I can talk you through the above solution. It is really easy when you know how and helpful to know how.

Comment: all the webpages I look at say the following should work but it doesn't wb.document.parentWindow.scroll 0&, 200&

Comment: Don't think it is tied to Excel.

Comment: thank you QHarr it looks like I will have to use and adapt your code, which I hopefully will be able to work out if i stare at it long enough, will have to apply it to my other macros I use to webscrape financial data as well, clearly my methods are not adequate, was just hoping to avoid rewriting everything

Comment: 1) I am offering to help you understand my code 2) This is a trickier page as I think you need to scoll nodes into view for them to be available 3) You should use free APIs where possible for financial data. 4) Don't know what rest of your code looks like but you should absolutely learn xmlhttp